# What are similar movements exist between Easter Celebrations in the Novus Ordo and the Extraordinary form of the Mass?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy, easter, extraordinary-form-of-the-mass, good-friday

Since we'll probably never have a TLM Mass at my parish for any of the Easter celebrations, I wanted to ask what the differences would be, but the differences seem to be too many to enumerate so I guess I'd like to concentrate on what the similarities are (i.e. if you time-travelled to 1962 what would you recognize).

The main points of the Easter Triduum celebrations as far as I see it are (in the NO)

Holy Thursday:

1. Washing Feet on Thursday
2. Moving Jesus out of the tabernacle to an altar of repose

Good Friday:

3. Passion on Good Friday
4. Lots of standing and kneeling during intercessions
5. Veneration of the Cross

Holy Saturday:

6. Lighting of the Easter Candle and procession in
7. Easter Proclamation
8. Readings in the Dark
9. Very happy Gloria with lots of Bells and Candles
10. Baptisms, Confirmations etc..
11. Renewal of Baptismal promises

If there's anything important I missed, please add it to your answer and I'll put it in the question as well. What I want to know is, are there movements in the Mass that have been taken out, added or adapted in the Novus Ordo and how do they compare to their traditional counterparts.

Comment: Do you want a dissertation here?

Comment: @ken Ok there's my ignorance being played out, I hear all sorts of interesting things for some of the super traditional contingent at my parish that I have no idea about. But  I'm just talking about the taking the things that average Catholics who attend NO Triduum liturgies find peculiar (i.e. things that aren't done any other time of the year) and mapping those to practices in the Traditional form of the Mass.  Not things that are lopped off altogether in the NO.

Comment: @Geremia This is definitely not a duplication of your [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/90584/how-do-the-1962-holy-week-ceremonies-compare-to-the-1954-ones) (**How do the 1962 Holy Week ceremonies compare to the 1954 ones?**) Thus I am reopening it.

Comment: @KenGraham How is it different?

Comment: @Geremia The 1962 Missal is definitely not the ***Novus Ordo*** of Pope St. Paul VI as in Peter’s question.

Comment: @ken I read though Geremia's answer and I'm not 100% sure what the distinctions would be.  Although I would like my question answered specifically - I definitely felt ok with the duplication distinction

Comment: @PeterTurner Geremia’s question does not deal with the ***Novus Ordo*** Mass at all, but between the celebrations between 1954 and 1962 editions.  You can close your own question if you think otherwise.